# Search for lines matching pattern in specific column in UNIX

Tags: unix, hadoop, awk, sed, grep

I am using HDFS to get data that meets a pattern in a specific column and want it to output the entire line. (Expecting ~2 million of 7 million lines to output)

Here is my exact situation:
I would like the entire line in a file where the data in the 4th column starts with a "5"

For example my data set:

```
HK|20151010|65|5005
KR|20151009|38|5092
MD|20150925|98|1943
BG|20150826|82|4892
HK|20151017|14|5002
```

I want the command to yield the following results:

```
HK|20151010|65|5005
KR|20151009|38|5092
HK|20151017|14|5002
```

Thank you so much! (Note: I cannot search the entire line because there are matches in other columns where the column data will begin with a 5)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

how about:

```
awk -F'|' '$4~/^5/' file
```

if the 4th column is always the last col, this line should work too:

```
grep '|5[^|]*$' file
```

Answer (score 1):

**grep** can be used to do this with some [^x]+x magic.  Here is the regular expression both in basic and extended forms:

```
grep '^\([^|]\+|\)\{3\}5'
egrep '^([^|]+\|){3}5'
```